# SSRS- how to get the largest check number and check date for max amount

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I am new to SSRS .

I need to get the Max check number , check date for the largest amount for year wise account.
I used sub query to get the max amount and check number. but I am not able get the largest check number in the ssrs grand total.

I need the report as like below,
ex:
2018 SALES

```
NUMBER OF CHECKS |AMOUNT
4                     $25,639.23
TOTAL AMOUNT          $25,639.23
LARGEST AMOUNT        $7,659.89
LARGEST CHECK NUM     958785576
CHECK DATE            9/9/2018
```

2019 MARKETING

```
NUMBER OF CHECKS    |AMOUNT
  7                  $12,455
TOTAL AMOUNT         $12,455
LARGEST AMOUNT       $5,364
LARGEST CHECK NUM    958786878
CHECK DATE           6/24/2019
```

Thanks for helping to get the above report.

Comment: This question requires a lot of work. We need to know what SQL you're using, and what the schema of the tables you're querying are.

In addition to that, you're really just trying to get a MAX(Column) for all of these. I'm not sure why that wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do this by using the ROW_NUMBER function in SQL Server to identify the record with the highest check amount.

```
SELECT BLAH, BLAAH...,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC) as ROW_NUM
FROM TABLE
```

The ROW_NUMBER will ORDER the checks by AMOUNT in descending order, making **1** the highest amount.

Your largest check would be the one where ROW_NUM = 1. To show the check number in the TOTAL line:

```
=MAX(IIF(Fields!ROW_NUM.Value = 1, Fields!CHECK_NUM.Value, NOTHING))
```

Comment: Thank you so much  that worked exactly what I want.